# Sublime Text: Disable Find in Selection

Tags: sublime-text-2

I sometimes have selected text when I open the find panel and Sublime Text defaults to "finding in selection". I never want this, any way I can disable it?

Comment: For what it's worth: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/78436-find-in-selection-shouldnt-be-the-default/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the bottom of the link provided by d_rail.

On OSX you can add the following to your

```
    { "keys": ["super+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": { "panel": "find", "in_selection": false } }
```

Or this for Windows or Linux

```
    { "keys": ["ctrl+f"], "command": "show_panel", "args": { "panel": "find", "in_selection": false } }
```

To your keybindings file to change this behaviour.